# LinqToEntitiesMetadataProvider for RIA Services in Visual Studio 2010 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, annotations, wcf-ria-services, rc

I'm having trouble moving from Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 to Visual Studio 2010RC.

Did all the adjustments regarding assemblies and namespaces but i cannot figure out how to get the following decorator resolved (for DomainService):

```
[LinqToEntitiesMetadataProvider(typeof(myEntities))]
```

Does anyone know how this must be adjusted?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no longer called this way. The new name is:

```
LinqToEntitiesDomainServiceDescriptionProvider
```

Pretty confusing, if one expects the names to be the same!!
Hope it helps someone in the future!